# /mnt/c/ is empty on WSL

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 inside the WSL. When I `cd /mnt/c/` and then `ls`, the C drive is empty.

I am not sure if it coincided with a `sudo apt-get upgrade` I used inside the WSL. Could this have caused the issue?

**UPDATE1:**
I tried to revert any package I installed today. Nothing changed.

**UPDATE2:**
I uninstalled Ubuntu, reinstalled it an everything works fine. It must have been somehting with the symbolic links. Somehow it lost the connection to the folders inside C drive. The question is why and what.

Comment: I recommend you **[edit]** this question to include the output of `mount` and of `df -h` (run from inside the WSL system).

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't see your comment first.I added some updates, that by uninstalling Ubuntu it worked. Could it be somehting with the symbolic links? And what?

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of the problem was. The *current* output of those commands may reveal if there's something unusual that was reproduced in the new system, but I don't know if it's really worth looking into further now. But you should update new newly installed Ubuntu system if you haven't (or at least install security updates), and if that causes the problem to come back, there will be something to work on again. Mounts in `/mnt` on WSL are typically [DrvFs mounts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/); I don't think symlinks are involved.

Comment: @EliahKagan is the Ubuntu version in the microsoft store directly connected with the rest distributions?

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean. If you're asking if, in the default configuration, running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` in Ubuntu in WSL retrieves updates from Ubuntu's official repositories even when Ubuntu was installed through the Microsoft Store, the answer is yes.

Comment: @EliahKagan thats what i meant. Thanks.